# getEmail and getDisplayName return null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The user is already login but when I use getEmail and getDisplayName method to get these values, they all return null.

```
  headerName.setText(user.getDisplayName());
  headerEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
```

When I debug it, the values are stored but these methods still return null!!!

[image: My debugger's values]

Comment: please provide all the relevant code.

Comment: @chota5511 Please share additional info. It looks as though from your image that the values may be correctly set, but is the getter method properly written? If the getter is properly written, are the values set before actually calling the getter, are you calling getter on the right object? It's difficult to answer the question with only the information you have provided.

Comment: Here is my project file with the problem [link](https://github.com/chota5511/TestFirebase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/chota5511/testfirebase/MainActivity.java) @sats

Comment: Please add the relevant code by editing your question and please reponde with @